# How to filter rows which include in PySpark window

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a dataframe like

```
|TRADEID|time_period|value|
+-------+-----------+-----+
|      1| 31-01-2019|    5|
|      1| 31-05-2019|    6|
|      2| 31-01-2019|   15|
|      2| 31-03-2019|   20|
+-------+-----------+-----+
```

Entries for some month are missing so I forward fill them with window operations

```
window = Window.partitionBy(['TRADEID'])\
               .orderBy('time_period')\
               .rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, 0)
filled_column = last(df['value'], ignorenulls = True).over(window)
df_filled = df.withColumn('value_filled', filled_column)
```

After this I get

```
|TRADEID|time_period|value|
+-------+-----------+-----+
|      1| 31-01-2019|    5|
|      1| 28-02-2019|    5|
|      1| 31-03-2019|    5|
|      1| 30-04-2019|    5|
|      1| 31-05-2019|    6|
|      2| 31-01-2019|   15|
|      2| 28-02-2019|   15|
|      2| 31-03-2019|   20|
+-------+-----------+-----+
```

However, I do not want to fill a month if the gap between this month and the last available month is more than 2 months. For example, in my case I want to get

```
|TRADEID|time_period|value   |
+-------+-----------+--------+
|      1| 31-01-2019|    5   |
|      1| 28-02-2019|    5   |
|      1| 31-03-2019|    5   |
|      1| 30-04-2019|    null|
|      1| 31-05-2019|    6   |
|      2| 31-01-2019|   15   |
|      2| 28-02-2019|   15   |
|      2| 31-03-2019|   20   |
+-------+-----------+--------+
```

How can I do this?
Have one more window operation that deletes entries with month that should not be filled beforehand? If it is a good way, please help me with code, I am bad at window operations.

Comment: My bad, I just needed to change   
```.rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, 0)``` to   
```.rowsBetween(-3, 0)```